# Testing significance of factors and covariates along with modeling causality among responses

Tags: multivariate-analysis, experiment-design, structural-equation-modeling

I'm wondering how to test the significance of factor(s) and/or covariate(s) along with modeling the causal relationship among responses.
Let me explain this with a concrete example.

#### Example:

Suppose a researcher observed four responses **Y1**, **Y2**, **Y3**, and **Y4** along with three covariates **X1**, **X2**, and **X3** from an experiment involving *ab* treatment combinations from a fixed factor ***A*** with *a* levels and a random factor ***B*** with *b* levels. Based on past experience, it is assumed four responses are correlated and **Y1** is also influenced by the other three (**Y2**, **Y3**, and **Y4**).

#### Question:

- How can I test the significance of Factors (***A*** and ***B***) and covariates (**X1**, **X2**, and **X3**) and causality among responses (**Y1**, **Y2**, **Y3**, and **Y4**) using a single model?

Comment: As far as the 'causality' part goes, this sounds like testing for [mediation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediation_%28statistics%29), but as the lead of that Wikipedia article says, the possibility of / methods for testing for mediation using empirical data have been challenged. I haven't made a thorough study of this, but i'd number myself among the skeptics.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe you can definitively do so.  The most difficult aspect will be the relationships among the 4 Y variables.  That there are "assumed" causal relationships among them does not help us to test causality.  In my limited understanding, a structural equation approach would assess the plausibility of an hypothesized model but would not test the correctness of such a model in any strict sense.